# Can the damage dealt by Slashing Wake be increased?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Warlock paragon path **Feytouched** grants the feature **Slashing Wake**:

> Slashing Wake (11th level): Once per turn, when you leave a square by teleporting, enemies adjacent to that square take damage equal to your Intelligence modifier.

Are there any feats, features, items, or other means of increasing this damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not really.**

It's not a hit and it's not a damage *roll*, which excludes most damage boosters right off the bat. It's untyped damage, so it can't benefit from vulnerability, and it's not a power, so you can't use anything to change its damage type.

You might take a look at the Long Night Scion paragon path, which has a similar ability that deals cold damage (and can therefore benefit from cold vulnerability from the frost cheese combo).

Answer (score 2):

**As Oblivious Sage said, you can not really increase the damage itself, but you can convert minions to damage this way.**

With a *Rain of Hammers Ki Focus* and good positioning you can kill one minion with a teleport, and deal 2+Enhancement bonus to another adjacent enemy.

With a Reaper's Axe, you kill a minion, finish the teleport, and then make an Eldritch Strike against a more worthy foe.

Of course 2 sessions after you put this together your DM will stop using minions alltogether.